# I cannot resolve a directory in my folder for some bizarre reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

Everytime I try to run my app.js file, I get an error that says

```
Cannot find module './models/recipe'
```

However, in my folder directory, I clearly have the models folder with my recipe.js file under it. And in my recipe.js file I have `const Recipe = require('./models/recipe');` as one of the first lines of the file.

None of these makes any sense. I am doing everything correctly as far as I know. Can anyone help me?

Here is my directory structure of my folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 Jun  1 13:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 May 30 18:33 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 Jun  1 13:39 .idea/
-rw-r--r-- 1 gabar 197609 725 Jun  1 13:14 app.js
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 Jun  1 13:16 models/
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 May 31 18:46 node_modules/
-rw-r--r-- 1 gabar 197609 783 May 31 18:46 package.json
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 May 31 17:03 public/
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 Jun  1 13:22 routes/
drwxr-xr-x 1 gabar 197609   0 May 31 14:07 views/
```

Comment: Can you share the directory structure ?

Comment: I don't know how to print my directory structure in git bash. Is there a command to do so?

Comment: add screenshot or `ls -la`

Comment: Is the file which is calling recipe.js inside another folder ? If so try "../modals/recipe"

Comment: The recipe.js file is in "/models"

Comment: Alright, I fixed it by rewriting it as "../models/recipe". Thank you all for helping me :)